# What is the added benefit of conducting a "multivariate multiple regression" over several "multiple regressions"?

Tags: regression, multivariate-regression

SPSS, Stata and SAS can all conduct multivariate multiple regressions (i.e. more than 2 continuous predictors and more than 2 outcomes) as GLM.
Consequently, the multivariate tests answers the question "which of the predictors (if any) is significantly related to at least one of the outcomes?". 
Because one has to refer to the univariate tables anyway to determine the direction of this effect (while controlling for multiple comparisons), I ask the question what is the added benefit of conducting the multivariate tests in the first place?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, I am aware of the possible duplicates. However, I am not asking about the differences between the two (I am fully aware of them), I am merely asking about the benefits of conducting one over the other.